# Where would an unlimited extent variable be allocated?

Tags: c#, delegates

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
public delegate int IntToInt(int n);

public class Foo 
{
    static int a = 2;

    static IntToInt b(int c) 
    {
        int d = a + c;
        Console.WriteLine(d);

        return delegate(int n) { return c + n; };
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b(3)(4));
    }
}
```

Why would `c` most likely be allocated on the **heap** rather than the **stack**?
I read that this is because `c` has **unlimited extent**.
Could you elaborate on this term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would `c` most likely be allocated on the heap rather than the stack?

Two `c`s in your example need allocation - `c`-the-parameter of `Foo.b`, and `c`-the-capture-of-delegate.

- `Foo.b`'s parameter is allocated on the stack, exactly the way you would expect.
- delegate's capture, on the other hand, is allocated on the heap, because the lifetime of `c` becomes tied to the lifetime of the delegate object, which is unlimited.